# netstat Foreign Address shows my hostname, TCP sockets refuse connections

Tags: windows, tcp, netstat

I am attempting to establish a TCP connection to a Windows machine running some third party software, unfortunately, I can not make the connection succeed.

Running:

```
netstat -an
```

Shows my service is bound:

```
Proto  Local Address  Foreign Address  State
TCP    0.0.0.0:1234   my-pc-name:0     LISTENING
```

Now, what is strange to me is that - the local address is correct, the service should be bound to all interfaces; what is incorrect, is the `Foreign Address`. Where is this set, and how would I change this?

It appears to me as if the network stack will only accept connections who originate from the same machine, and will throw a CONNECTION_REFUSED for all other devices attempting to send in a packet.

Where is this Foreign Address set, and how can I change it?

Comment: From admin elevated command prompt, run this command: `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="TCP 1234 Inbound" dir=in action=allow remoteip=any localip=any protocol=TCP localport=1234 remoteport=1234 profile=any` and then try accessing that port remotely from other hosts—another quick way to confirm the Windows Firewall is blocking the connections even though the app is listening on the port 1234 is to disable Windows Firewall and then test the connection from an external machine. If you can connect, Windows FW is disabling to open up an explicit rule to allow the needed TCP port.

Comment: To Pimp, you should note that you're not answering the question he asked about the dns.  To Matt the questioner,  try control panel..system...advanced system settings..computer name (then see 'full computer name', see that name there,  https://i.imgur.com/kfgtukZ.png  then compare with.  this screen  https://i.imgur.com/Copc02m.png

Comment: @MattClark - Have you simply tried my suggestion yet and see what happens? Let me know if that helped you any or not.